# How can I search and find parent document which meet criteria in other collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm using meteor and mongo db

I have two collections with a one to many structure

Hotels:

```
{
    _id:1,
    name: "Hotel 1"
},
{
    _id:2,
    name: "Hotel 2"
}
```

Bookings

```
{_id:1,
    hotel_id_:1,
    date: "2016-05-06",
    num_nights: 2,
    dates: ["2016-05-06", "2016-05-06"]
},
{_id:2,
    hotel_id:1
    date: "2016-05-04",
    num_nights: 1,
    dates: ["2016-05-04"]
},
{_id:3,
    hotel_id:2
    date: "2016-05-01",
    num_nights: 3,
    dates: ["2016-05-01", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-03"]
}
```

I could also save the hotels like this, where the bookings are a direct child of the parent:

```
{
    _id:1,
    name: "Hotel 1",
    bookings:[
        {_id:1,
            hotel_id_:1,
            date: "2016-05-06",
            num_nights: 2,
            dates: ["2016-05-06", "2016-05-06"]
        },
        {_id:2,
            hotel_id:1
            date: "2016-05-04",
            num_nights: 1,
            dates: ["2016-05-04"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to find a way to find Hotels Based on 3 Criteria for any given dates

- City Name (Regex - I can manage this)
- Availability (Given by the hotel - I can manage this)
- No clashing Bookings for the given dates

Edit:

Hotels and Bookings are metaphores for what my actual setup is, but they're very similar.
**Assume a hotel is either booked or not for a given date** there are no 'rooms'

/edit

I can find bookings for a given hotel, but I don't know how to combine the whole lot to find hotels that meet the first two requirements but also have no clashing bookings, because bookings at the moment are in a separate collections

Is there a way to find the hotels that first meet the first two criteria then filter out those who don't meet the second - without looping through each document manually

Thanks! I'd be very happy to clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like there could be still issue with bookings as there is no capacity given.
In that scenario we don't want to have customer booked three nights in three different rooms - so this should be provided as a hotel details.
To simplify that we could use just capacity (rooms, or combination of persons/rooms) then we will be able to provide information for customer about availability.

```
hotel {
    id : 1,
    roomsCount : 200
}

bookings {
    id : 1,
    hotelId : 1,
    roomsTaken : 1
    date : [201605-05, 2016-05-06]
}, {
    id : 2,
    hotelId : 1,
    roomsTaken : 3
    date : [2016-05-06, 2016-05-07]
}, {
    id : 1,
    hotelId : 1,
    roomsTaken : 10
    date : [2016-05-05, 2016-05-06, 2016-05-07]
}
```

let's say we want to chek if we have 4 rooms on 2015-05-06

```
db.bookings.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                date : 2016-05-06
            }
        }, //select only bookings having this date
        {
            $unwind : date
        }, {
            $match : {
                date : 2016-05-06
            }
        }, //select only bookings having this date
        {
            $group : {
                _id : null,
                roomsTaken : {
                    $sum : "$roomsTaken"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

so when we get how many rooms are taken, then we can provide how many rooms are free.

**As an extend we can have a pool of rooms number and mark them as free/reserved/inUse**

Comment: Thanks for this. You've definitely pointed me in the right direction. 
However I probably should have mentioned that hotel and bookings were just metaphores for the actual collections, and I didn't think about the case you pointed out. 
In my scenario a 'hotel' is either booked on that night or not. There are no rooms per se. Sorry, I'll clarify above

Answer (score 1):

If you add moment package (momentjs:moment) you can check if two dates conflict like this:

```
var rangeOne = moment.range(startDate, endDate);  //you should define your start and end dates
var rangeTwo = moment.range(otherStartDate, otherEndDate); //you should also define the dates here

if(rangeTwo.overlaps(rangeOne) == true) {
    //if dates conflict, do something
} else {
    //do something when dates don't conflict
}
```

You can also use the code above in forEach() which you probably need as you need to check if the dates conflict with any of the bookings. Update your question with your new codes if this is not enough explanation and I'll edit my answer with actual codes you can use for your specific needs.